# How do I attach an interior wall between 2 trusses/studs?

Tags: walls, doors, studs, interior, architecture

I want to build interior wall which should go along trusses and studs. I need to install 72 inch French doors in the middle of the wall, so I need to support the wall from top and bottom. I can drill holes in the tile and slab to  support bottom 2x4 , but I'm not sure how to secure the wall from the ceiling.

I was thinking that I would connect trusses with a few 2x4s and screw the wall to those 2x4s, and same between 2 studs. but I'm not sure if that's correct approach.

How can I build that wall?

The wall I want to build is blue one on the picture. There are no trusses right above that wall. The nearest truss is located around 10 inches to the side. Also there are no studs on the wall to connect a new wall to (nearest stud is around 10 inches to the side).

There is no attic above, there is a 2nd floor above.

I want to build the wall but it won't be supported by a truss from the top and by the stud from 1 of the walls (2nd wall has the stud at the exact position I need).

Picture of the trusses above drywall
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I read your edit and think "so what". You still install blocking as per your accepted answer. The only difference is that you cut back drywall to expose the trusses/studs on either side of the new wall, install blocking, install the new wall, then fix the drywall. Just make sure you include nailers for the drywall where the new corners (both wall and ceiling) are, otherwise, you'll have drywall flapping in the breeze. No, a corner bead and drywall mud isn't sufficient to hold it in place.

Comment: I suppose you could pull up the floor above, but frankly, fixing drywall seems like a _much_ easier option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: blocking is installed at intervals between the studs/trusses on either side, and the new wall framing is attached to the blocking.

Comment: I've heard that I can't attach anything to trusses. Or this is an exception?

Comment: @Rainmaker, hanging stuff from trusses could be a problem. They tend to get built with _exactly_ the required strength, so technically added load can easily push them out of conformance. But blocking between bottom truss chords is perfectly normal. From [IRC R602.10.8.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.10.8.2), for instance, note the "Where required by this section, blocking between rafters or roof trusses shall be attached to top plates of braced wall panels and to rafters and roof trusses in accordance with Table R602.3(1)."

Comment: @popham Don't we add extra load to trusses when we connect the wall (which will have french door on it) to the blocking? Since blocking connects trusses, it should split the load between them, right?

Comment: @Rainmaker, go in the attic and look at the detail implemented by the framers for that wall stub in line with your wall. Copy their detail. If you see a gap and clips, you'll want to look into https://www.strongtie.com/trussclips_platedtrussconnectors/tc_roofclips/p/stc.stct.dtc. Gap and no clips? They might have used something like https://www.strongtie.com/strongdrive_interiorwoodscrews/sdpw_screw/p/strong-drive-sdpw-deflector-screw. For drywall with a gap, check into https://www.strongtie.com/miscellaneousconnectors_woodconnectors/ds_stop/p/ds. You'll probably just find blocking, though.

Comment: @popham  sorry for the late response and thanks for the info. I can't fin't en example of how to do truss blocking correctly. Should I just drill throgh the truss and put a screw to another 2x4(blocking) ? or use connectors? Maybe there are some resources?

Comment: @Rainmaker, where it ties into that wall at the image's top left, isn't that an interior wall that is perfectly analogous to the one that you intend to build? Is it's interface to the trusses not accessible from the attic? If it is accessible, then what's going on between your trusses along that wall. What's joining the wall to the ceiling? Describe whatever additional investigation you've done in your question above, though, so I can delete some of this litter on kreemoweet's answer.

Comment: @popham Edited, added a picture, hope it makes sense now

Comment: @Rainmaker, from your old image, look at the upper left corner of the image. Your hypothetical top plate drawn along the ceiling ends at an existing corner, with your new wall extending one of the existing walls that meet at this corner. You need to examine how the builder connected the top plate of this existing wall to the ceiling. There's probably blocking spanning from truss to truss, but there may be clips or some other affordance that keep the wall plumb but allow the trusses to deflect without interference.

Comment: @popham I see what you mean now. So from the other side you are talking about- I have load bearing wall, and this is exterior wall, which holds trusses. I attached another picture